# How to perform update function for checkbox with push array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, temp

I have function update checkbox but I have problem with pushing the existed `db_fruit_id` into the array if user perform update function.

Fruitlist API

```
 "status": "success",
    "result": [
        {
            "fruit": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Apple"
            }
            "fruit": {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Grape"
            }
        },
```

I have this getFruitDetails API

```
"fruit": {
   "fruit_data": [
      {
       "db_fruit_id": 101,
       "fruit_id": 1,
       "fruit_name": "Apple"
      },
      {
        "db_fruit_id": 102,
        "fruit_id": 2,
        "fruit_name": "Orange"
       },
]}
```

With the current code if user did not perform update checkbox function I will get this output (This is output that I want to achieve)

```
Fruit, [{"db_fruit_id":121,"fruit_id":3},{"db_fruit_id":122,"fruit_id":4}]
```

But when user perform update function on the checkbox function its fetching 1 fix `db_fruit_id`.

```
Fruit, [{"db_fruit_id":121,"fruit_id":3},{"db_fruit_id":121,"fruit_id":4},{"db_fruit_id":121,"fruit_id":5}]
```

How do I fix this problem ?

```js
function getFruit() {
  return axios.get(`http://localhost/getFruitList`);
}

function getFruitDetails(id) {
  return axios.get(`http://localhost/getDetails?fruit_id=${id}`);
}

Promise.all([getFruit(), getFruitDetails(id)])
  .then(function(results) {

    const fruit = results[0];
    const fruitData = results[1];


    if (fruit.data.status == 'success') {
      fruit.data.result.map((e) => {
        $('#fruit_type').append(`<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="fruit_type_id_${e.fruit.id}" name="chk_fruit" value="${e.fruit.id}">
                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="fruit_type_id_${e.fruit.id}">${e.fruit.name}</label>
                        <input type="text" id="fruit_dbId_${e.fruit.id}"  hidden/>
                                                                    
    
                    </div>`);
      });
    }
    if (fruitData.data.status == 'success') {
      fruitData.fruit_data.map((e) => {
        $(`#fruit_type_id_${e.fruit_type_id}`).prop('checked', true);
        $(`#fruit_dbId_${e.fruit_type_id}`).val(e.db_id);
        fruit_temp.push({
          "db_fruit_id": e.db_fruit_id,
          "fruit_id": e.fruit_type_id,

        });
        $(document).on('change', 'input[name="chk_fruit"]', function() {
          fruit_temp = [];
          $('input[name="chk_fruit"]:checked').each(function() {
            fruit_temp.push({
              "db_id": $("fruit_db_id").val(), // how do I get the db_id here using the details value?
              "fruit_id ": $(this).val(),
            });
          });
        });


      });
    }


  });
```

The reason why I have two IDs for the fruit item is because

1. db_fruit_id - shows that the data and value already existed in the database.
2. fruit_id - is to refer to the fruitlist API

If user add new fruit the new db_fruit_id will be assigned in the backend part.

Comment: Why do you have two ids for fruits?
Before updating your array you can check if the fruit already exists on the array and ignore it.
You can also use Array.filter if that helps

Comment: Two ids is because `db_fruit_id` is to show the value already existed in the database, if user add on new value the `db_fruit_id` will assign the id in the backend.